# Intellij Class '' already exists

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spring-security

I need to customize the spring security LogoutController a little bit so I have copied the controller from the plugin to the same package location in my grails-app/controllers

The controller is used instead of the original one because the plugins are compiled first -> the original will be overriden.

Now my problem is that intellij 12.1.7 complains that the Class 'LogoutController' already exists in package 'grails.plugin.security' ... ofcourse :( but thats no error !

I could not find anything to hide that error in the validation setup.

[image]

Comment: but why do you want to use original package? instead of app package

Comment: I have to use this package because I want to override that controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails controllers do not take package into account: only 1 LoginContoller will be used regardless of the package: (default url mapping is /$controller/$action?/$id? no place for package there).
The same goes for Domain classes.

To override the LoginController from ANY plugin in your app you just need to define a LoginController in the app, no matter the package.

However, if you define it in the exact same package of the plugin you're creating a conflict that would need to be resolved by class loader precedence. That should be the same (app first) but I wouldn't take that for granted. Hence the error IntelliJ is showing.